# 404 Error After Adding Argument To URL Path

Tags: django, django-urls

Ive got a users profile page and an update_profile page.

My projects urls.py:

```
re_path(r'^profile/(?P<username>[\w-]+)/$', include('users.urls')),
```

My users.urls:

```
path('', views.profile, name='profile'),
path('update_profile', views.update_profile, name='update_profile'),
```

Prior to adding the username argument to the url both of these links were working. Since adding the username argument, I can access the profile page but the update_profile page throws a 404 error. My understanding is that if the address bar reads `www.site/profile/testuser/update_profile` the projects urls.py will strip the `www.site/profile/testuser/` and pass just `update_profile` to the profile apps urls.py, which then should match the path ive given.

1. Why isnt this working?
2. On my profile page I have a check that ensures the `username` passed in matches the logged in user (so users can only access their own profiles). I will need a similar check on the update_profile page, but currently arent passing `username` to the update profile page. How could I perform this check without passing it in a second time like `/profile/testuser/update_profile/testuser`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the answers to your questions:

**1.** Your url is not working because of there is a `$` at the end of `users.urls` url. `$` is a zero width token which means an end in regex. So remove it.

**2.** You do not need to add `<username>` at the `profile_update` url. If you are using [**`UpdateView`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview), then add [`slug_url_kwarg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin) attribute to UpdateView, like:

```py
class MyUpdateView(UpdateView):
   slug_url_kwarg = "username"
```

If you are using function based view, then simply use:

```py
def myview(request,username):
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just have one more issue if you dont mind helping me again. My views all work fine except for my form which renders the form. I cant find how to pass both the form (context), and the username. This was my original code ```return render(request, 'users/update_profile.html', context)```. Something like this doesnt work ```return render(request, 'users/update_profile.html', {'username':User.objects.get(username=username), 'context':context})```. Thanks again

Comment: just add user in context like `context['user_object'] = User.objects.get()`. But if you are using logged in user, then there is no need to do that. You can access it via `{{ user }}` in template.